# Bundled object shows null after send to another fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am developing android application .I  extends Fragment  class to all java classes in my app .I want to send data from fragment to another fragment (AllDeals-> CarDetails).For sending data I create parcelable class object  and send this object to another fragment.But in new fragment it always  shows null data.i tried with lot time of time but I am not get successed.Already  I waste lot of times on this so I decided to post a questions.So I requested you please solve my problem.
I initialize CarBean like that

```
 obj = new CarBean();
        obj.setName("deepak");
        obj.setPrize(txt_carprize.getText().toString());
        obj.setAvgPrize(txt_vat.getText().toString());
        obj.setImage("R.drawable.img"+currentposition);
```

Here is my code

```
 public class AllDeals extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener 
{
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     BaseFragment fragment = new AllDeals();
    bundle.putParcelable("cardetails", obj);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

And this class i read Bundled object

```
public class CarDetails extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener
{
 Bundle bundledata=getArguments();
 CarBean carbean=bundledata.getParcelable("cardetails");
 String name=carbean.getName();
}
```

And Here is Java Bean class

```
public class CarBean implements Parcelable
{
    String name,prize,avgprize,image;



     public  CarBean(Parcel in)
        {
            name=in.readString();
            prize=in.readString();
            avgprize=in.readString();
            image=in.readString();
        }
    public CarBean() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPrize(String prize)
    {
        this.prize=prize;
    }
    public String getPrize()
    {
        return prize;
    }
    public void  setAvgPrize(String avgprize)
    {
        this.avgprize=avgprize;
    }

    public String getAvgPrize()
    {
        return avgprize;
    }

    public void setImage(String image)
    {
        this.image=image;

    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        return  image;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /*
     here we store the data into parcle object

     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        out.writeString(name);
        out.writeString(prize);
        out.writeString(avgprize);
        out.writeString(image);
    }


    /*  retrive the data from  parcel object */






    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CarBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CarBean>() 
            {

                @Override
                public CarBean createFromParcel(Parcel in) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /* this method  call CarBean Constructor */

                    return new CarBean(in);
                }

                @Override
                public CarBean[] newArray(int size) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return new CarBean[size];
                }
    };
}
```

Comment: The code looks incomplete, or misplaced. Are you sure the object is not null when inserting it into the bundle?

Comment: already i initialise CarBean object in fragment  like obj = new CarBean();
        obj.setName("deepak");
        obj.setPrize(txt_carprize.getText().toString());
        obj.setAvgPrize(txt_vat.getText().toString());
        obj.setImage("R.drawable.img"+currentposition);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print/log your `obj` right before this

```
bundle.putParcelable("cardetails", obj);
```

to make sure it is not null.

Comment: You were rightit is showing null object that's why my app is crashed.Could you tell me where to need change in code.Your help is really appreciated

Comment: Simply make sure that the initialization code is called before bundling the object. Put some debug log where you create `obj = new CarBean();` and see if it ever gets called, and if it's called before or after the `bundle.putParcelable(...)`.

Comment: i am not get proper solution .i have change code and i am try to send  only single string to other fragment but other fragment it showing null data.please give me sample code so i can move further